# Preview and pdf annotation opacity

Tags: pdf, preview

I'm running into issues with Preview on 10.10.2 and annotation opacities. Preview seems to not honor opacities set by other programs, and clears all annotation opacities in a file when saving a new version.

Specifically, I'm using PDFs that have been previously annotated with another program (Foxit PDF reader in Windows, or Adobe Reader on Mac) to have 40% opacity at a given color. When viewed in Preview, these annotation are displayed at 100% opacity (completely opaque) and are thus much darker in color). When I make a new annotation in Preview and save the edited file, it resets all opacity values to 100%.

Is there any way to get Preview to honor these opacity values, or at the very least not clear them when saving a file? I don't want to have to switch to using Adobe Reader on the Mac (which does display opacities correctly), but I may have to.

Comment: Instead save did you try export as PDF in preview

Comment: I am not really surprised with this Preview.app behavior. I may be wrong, but I think, Quartz (the PDF engine in OSX) is too far backward (based on PDF 1.3 at best) that it can treat transparencies properly. And when saving you apparently run into one of the many improper ways Preview uses when saving the document. In short, unless someone comes up with a solution, the best is to avoid Preview.app, when annotations (of any kind) are involved, and/or the document is to be saved.